# How can i parse data values from sky-websense?

Tags: json, cloud, contiki

Friends, I did some basic work in cooja like collecting temperature and light sensor values through sky-Websense and ipv6.Now, I could see both sensor values in the browser using the mote IP address. My problem here is i want to use those sensor mote values in my cloud application how can i parse those values to my cloud application. I know json will work.
 But I have no idea on how to work on the motes such that their values will be parsed to send over the internet.

Any useful advice is most welcome guys.

Answer (score 0):

Send the data as a JSON string.
e.g. {"temp":26, "light":400}

If the question is about how to send it from the mote I would suggest either a CoAP (Erbium) or UDP server.
UDP is probably the most straight forward solution where you can just parse the incoming UDP messages and on a correct request send back the data.
The Erbium method is quite easy to and there are examples for it in the repo.

Comment: Really thanzz for your suggestion johan will look on to it and will update you soon

Comment: Johan what steps should i follow to transefer it as a udp message for example am having one mote which has some data output,firstly where should i start to collect those output , what are all the consecutive steps in cooja?? kindly clear me out bro !!

Comment: Look at the udp-echo-server and then modify the return data based on the received data.